# Why is this function scoping error occuring with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have the following function:

```
function updateStatuses() {
    $.each($('.status-badge'), function (i, value) {
        value.removeClass('badge-known');
    });
    $.post("/Diagnostics/Update", {  }, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            setStatus(this.Id, this.Infos, this.Errors, this.Warnings);
        });
    });
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $.each($('.status-badge:not(.badge-known)'), function(i, value) {
            value.addClass('badge-unknown');
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Basically, I'm updating a group of badges from an AJAX call. If, after 1000ms, any certain badge hasn't been updated, it gains the `badge-unknown` class.

The function above is called as such:

```
$(function () { updateStatuses(); });
```

My problem is that `value.removeClass('badge-known');` gives the following error:

```
TypeError: value.removeClass is not a function
```

If I comment that line out, the timeout function throws the same error on `value.removeClass('badge-unknown');`

The confusing thing is, `addClass` and `removeClass` are used in `setStatus`, which is defined just below the above function. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @apsillers there's no need for _any_ `.each()` call on the `removeClass` and `addClass` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is a dom node, not a jQuery object. Try

```
$(value).removeClass('badge-known');
```

Comment: However, alnitak's answer has a better alternative. Two of those `$.each()` aren't needed (the two that are throwing the error).

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to use `.each` when calling standard jQuery methods.  Most such methods will happily iterate directly over a set of elements.

Also, there's no need for the anonymous function wrapper around your main `document.ready` handler:

Your whole code can be just this:

```
function updateStatuses() {
    $('.status-badge').removeClass('badge-known');

    $.post("/Diagnostics/Update", {  }, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
            setStatus(this.Id, this.Infos, this.Errors, this.Warnings);
        });
    });

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('.status-badge:not(.badge-known)').addClass('badge-unknown');
    }, 1000);
}

$(updateStatuses);
```

Comment: I'm accepting Kevin's answer since he identified my actual problem, but +1 since this is much more elegant than how I was trying before!

Comment: @DanRasmussen actually in a `.each()` loop like that you'd be better with `$(this)` than `$(value)`, but never mind ;-)

Comment: I tried that too (`this.removeClass`) and simply tried `value` out of desperation.. Haha